# Number of war files on Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

How many war files be deployed on a Tomcat 6.0 server?

Comment: I'd guess 65536 :)

Comment: Is this theoretical or you actually want to deploy LOADS of wars onto Tomcat?

Comment: This question is a bit strange, it's like asking "how many programs can I install on my computer". If you are writing software that reaches this limit, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: what are they good for?

Comment: @Bozho I'd actually wager that it's higher than that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a hard-coded limit. It will depend on the server resources you have available (particularly RAM), the amount of resources required by the particular webapps, and levels of usage. These things all vary very widely, so nobody will be able to give you a concrete answer.